# 1:250 streams data - USA wide - where can I find it?

Tags: data, hydrology, nhd

I have 1:250 streams data for a few western states. I find this scale to be excellent in many settings as base hydro data.

I have never been able to find a USA or better yet, NA wide dataset of this scale. Does anything like this exist for the USA or NA?

Look at the attached Idaho jpg for an example of this data [image]

Comment: Have you checked out the TIGER shapefiles provided by the Census Bureau?  http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html  They have an FTP access to download multiple linear or area water shapefiles.  I do not know what scale however the data was acquired at.

Comment: yep.. looked at Tiger.. I am looking specifically for 1:250

Answer (score 1):

The [National Hydrologic Dataset](http://nhd.usgs.gov/data.html) offers all hydrology data in 1:100,000 (medium res) or 1:24,000 (high res) for all of the US.